# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, owin

After having read and tried the answers on stackExchange I am still getting a null value for result in the below code:

```
    typeOfIMydServiceBase.Assembly
            .GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(exportedType => typeOfMydServiceBase != exportedType && typeOfMydServiceBase.IsAssignableFrom(exportedType))
            .Select(mydServiceType => new
            {
                serviceType = mydServiceType,
                interfaceType = mydServiceType.GetInterfaces().First(@interface => @interface != typeOfIMydServiceBase && typeOfIMydServiceBase.IsAssignableFrom(@interface))
            })
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(registrationInfo => container.Register(registrationInfo.interfaceType, () =>
            {
                var method = serviceActivatorType
                    .GetMethod("GetService", serviceActivatorParams)
                    .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { registrationInfo.interfaceType });
                var result = method.Invoke(new ServiceActivator(), null);

                return result;
            }, WebApiRequestLifestyleWithDisposal));
```

result keeps coming back as null and when I use an Object[] {null} or Object[]{} or Object[]{null,null,etc} I get parameter mismatches.

Note: this is the error message I recieve for the above code:

> Line 156:                        .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { registrationInfo.interfaceType });
>
> Line 157:
>
> Line 158:                    var result = method.Invoke(new ServiceActivator(), null);
>
> Line 159:
>
> Line 160:                    return result;

Does anyone know what's happening here and how I can fix it????

```
{
public class ServiceActivator
{
    public ServiceActivator();
    public ServiceActivator(IServiceConfigurationReader configurationReader);

    public T GetService<T>();
    public T GetService<T>(string key);
}
```

}

Also pertinent to the above is the registration of the services used. See below:

```
//Scan and register business servics
        var typeOfIMydServiceBase = typeof(IMydServiceBase);
        var typeOfMydServiceBase = typeof(MydServiceBase);
        var serviceActivatorType = typeof(ServiceActivator);
        var serviceActivatorParams = new Type[0];
```

Update: using typeof(string) at serviceActivator Params works however I am getting an unhandled exception futher down. Here is the new error:

```
Line 166:                    p.ServiceContainer = container;
Line 167:                });
Line 168:
Line 169:                container.RegisterWebApiControllers(config);
Line 170:            }
```

which pertains to the following code:

```
var typeOfIMydServiceBase = typeof(IMydServiceBase);
        var typeOfMydServiceBase = typeof(MydServiceBase);
        var serviceActivatorType = typeof(ServiceActivator);
        var serviceActivatorParams = new Type[] { typeof(string) };
        
        typeOfIMydServiceBase.Assembly
            .GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(exportedType => typeOfMydServiceBase != exportedType && typeOfMydServiceBase.IsAssignableFrom(exportedType))
            .Select(mydServiceType => new
            {
                serviceType = mydServiceType,
                interfaceType = mydServiceType.GetInterfaces().First(@interface => @interface != typeOfIMydServiceBase && typeOfIMydServiceBase.IsAssignableFrom(@interface))
            })
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(registrationInfo => container.Register(registrationInfo.interfaceType, () =>
            {
                
                var method = serviceActivatorType
                    .GetMethod("GetService", serviceActivatorParams)
                    .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { registrationInfo.interfaceType });
           
                var result = method.Invoke(new ServiceActivator(), null);

                return result;
            }, WebApiRequestLifestyleWithDisposal));
        {

            container.RegisterInitializer<IMydServiceBase>(p =>
            {
                p.ServiceContainer = container;
            });

            container.RegisterWebApiControllers(config);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your `GetService` method signature? Does it parameter allow `null` (e.x value types,..)

Comment: Have you checked that there's data that matches your filter criteria? If you've not got any data or you've got an unexpected value in one (or more) of your search terms you could well be legitimately getting no results.

Comment: @KhanhTO further to your question GetService is defined within the ServiceActivator function   {
    public class ServiceActivator
    {
        public ServiceActivator();
        public ServiceActivator(IServiceConfigurationReader configurationReader);

        public T GetService<T>();
        public T GetService<T>(string key);
    }
}

Comment: @ChrisF so I will go through all the parameters in the filter and look for any outliers.

Comment: try replacing `.GetMethod("GetService", serviceActivatorParams)` with `.GetMethod("GetService", new Type[] { typeof(string) })`

Comment: @KhanhTO  serviceActivator Params is presently defined as such  var serviceActivatorParams = new Type[0];    when I try to use typeof(string) I get a cannot convert from system.Type to system.Type[]

Comment: it should be `new Type[] { typeof(string) }`. If you use `serviceActivatorParams`, it should be `var serviceActivatorParams = new Type[] { typeof(string) }`

Comment: APologies for the delay had to update db building and attempting to run now

Comment: what is the new error?

Comment: Could not load type 'MYD.Services.NotificationServices.Sandbox.IEmailsTesting' from assembly 'MYD.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: Your code has various errors. That error should not be related to this question. Can you drill down in the code to find out more about this new error? Maybe post another question with detailed information specific to this problem.

Comment: Apologies and thank you. This solution solved the problem at hand. Thank you very much @KhanhTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var method = serviceActivatorType
                    .GetMethod("GetService", serviceActivatorParams)`

returns **`public T GetService<T>();`** with `var serviceActivatorParams = new Type[0];` (from comment discussion in the question)

BUT this line:

```
var result = method.Invoke(new ServiceActivator(), null);
```

is going to invoke this method:

**`public T GetService<T>(string key);`**

passing `null` as the value for `string key`.

There is no parameter to be passed for `public T GetService<T>();`, that's why it throws an exception.

To fix your problem, try:

```
var serviceActivatorParams = new Type[] { typeof(string) };
```

or invoke your method without the `null` parameter:

```
var result = method.Invoke(new ServiceActivator());
```